# Significado de ///

Tags: c++, c

¿Cuál es el significado de poner en una línea `///` y código en lenguaje c?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Cuál es el significado de poner en una línea `///` y código en lenguaje c?

El mismo significado que...

```
//
```

Es un comentario de una línea, el comentario es a partir de la doble barra ascendente, por lo tanto el ejemplo anterior es un comentario vacío y este:

```
///
```

Es un comentario que contiene el carácter `/`, mientras que este:

```
/// @brief
```

Es un comentario que contiene el texto `/ @brief`. Nada de lo que esté contenido en un comentario tiene ningún significado en lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c).

---

Algunas herramientas de generación de documentación buscan comentarios escritos de una manera determinada para generar documentación, por ejemplo [doxygen](https://doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) usa comentarios como el que muestras o estos otros:

```
//! Esto es un comentario doxygen
//! @param a el parámetro a
//! @return la función devuelve cosas
int f(int a);
```

Probablemente estés encontrando comentarios preparados para ser pasados por una herramienta de generación de documentación.

Answer (score 1):

En lenguaje C, **un comentario de una sola línea comienza con `//`, comienza y termina en la misma línea.**

Para comentar en una sola línea, puedes realizarlo de dos formas:

Conteniendo el texto entre `/*` y `*/`:

```
/* Autor: kik3-912 */
```

y también agregando el prefijo de doble barra `//` para comentar líneas individuales, ejemplo:

```
// Autor: kik3-912
```

Esta forma de comentar se puede usar con la mayoría de los compiladores de C modernos y también es usado en lenguaje C++, así como otros lenguajes.

```
/******************************************************************************
                          Program C Compiler.    
*******************************************************************************/    
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    ///
    //Programa 1
    ///
    
    // declara e inicializa la variable string
    char str[] = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/";
    //Imprime la variable.
    printf("La cadena es: %s\n", str);
    int length = 0;
    length = strlen(str);
    // desplegando la longitud de la cadena
    printf("Longitud de la cadena: %d", length);
  
    return 0;
    /// Termina mi programa
}
```